# Regex slightly different in Ruby 2?

Tags: ruby, regex, posix

I just ported a small gem from Ruby 1.9.3 to the spiffy new Ruby 2.0.0.  The only change I had to make was in a regular expression.

Under 1.9.3, the following regex would match any string containing characters other than digits, number-related punctuation, and whitespace (including non-breaking space).

```
/[^[[:space:]]\d\-,\.]/
```

Under 2.0.0, I had to move the Posix space class away from the start of the negation class.

```
/[^\d\-,\.[[:space:]]]/
```

I haven't found this change mentioned in the patch notes I've reviewed.  Is it documented anywhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The regular expression engine has been changed to Onigmo (based on [Oniguruma](http://oniguruma.rubyforge.org/oniguruma/)) and this might be causing issues.

As far as I can tell, you're declaring the regular expression incorrectly. The second set of brackets is not required:

```
/[^[:space:]\d\-,\.]/
```

The `[:space:]` declaration is only invalid inside of a set so you will see it appear as `[[:space:]]` if used in isolation. In your case you have several other additions to the set.

I'm not sure why `\s` would not have sufficed in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer.  I had noticed the change to Onigmo, but didn't think through the possibility that it would make the regex any stricter.  I also appreciate the tutelage on posix classes.  I don't use them frequently, and hadn't grasped what conditions require the double square brackets.  Thanks!

Under 1.9.3-p385 the `\s` space character class failed to match non-breaking spaces, `0xA0`, hence my use of the `[:space:]` posix class.  I'll test the `\s` under 2.0.0-p0 and report back here if it seems to work.

Comment: That's true. As `\xA0` is only a non-breaking space if you're using Latin1 as your character set and not UTF-8.

Comment: My tests in the last few minutes indicate that `\s` under 2.0.0-p0 still does not match `0xA0`, just as in 1.9.3.  Also, placing the posix space class immediately after the `^` makes this regex fail under 2.0.0.  Placing it after the `\d` or after the `\.` makes it match as expected.  I wonder whether the Onigmo developers consider this desired behaviour, or an unexpected wrinkle.

Comment: `\s` has a very strict list of characters it accepts. `[:space:]` is a much more generous character-set specific version with different rules for UTF-8, Latin1 and ISO-1252 among others. If you need that sort of thing, probably best to use the set than roll your own. Not sure why it wouldn't work in Onigmo, though.

Comment: The `[:space:]` works when it's not at the front of the negation class.  <shrug>  I should submit a bug on Onigmo, perhaps?

Comment: If you've narrowed it down to that particular case, sounds like a bug to me. `/[^[:space:]]/` should represent the set of all non-space characters.